# How to reload a sectionHeader title in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to reload the method : `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?` , only refresh the title. but don't want to reload the whole tableView . is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you cant reload only sectionHeader. 
The best you can do is to reload the section which contains that header using

`self.tableView.reloadSections([1], with: .automatic)`

where 1 is the index of section which you wanna refresh. Pass the index of whichever section you wanna reload.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
let header = table.headerView(forSection: 0) as! URCutomHeaderView
header.someMethod()//configure new data
```